# Computing: $\sum \limits_{n=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\times 2n}{{(2n-1)\times (2n+1)}} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

Which is the easiest way to find the value of $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\times 2n}{{(2n-1)\times (2n+1)}} $$

There is a hint, which says we can use $$ {{1 \over 2}\over{r-1}} + {{1 \over 2}\over{r+1}} = {r \over{(r-1) (r+1)} } $$

but I am not sure how, any ideas guys?

Comment: did you really mean $2^n$ or $2n$?

Comment: In case you did mean $2n$ instead of $2^n$ try substituting $r=2n$, otherwise the hint doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Like in the previous comments, I am assuming there is a typo, it should be $2n$.  Using the hint, write down the sum of the first $4$ terms.

Comment: and note it collapses...

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, @Andre post your hint as an answer, I want to accept it.

Comment: A perfectly good answer has been posted by David Mitra. If I had written an answer (unnecessary now), I would first show (using the partial fractions hint) what the first few terms look like.  That is only a rhetorical difference.

Comment: Oops! I didn't refreshed the page before commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the hint, use partial fractions to write
$$
{(-1)^{n-1}2n\over (2n-1)(2n+1) }={1\over2}{(-1)^{n-1}\over 2n+1}+{1\over2}{(-1)^{n-1}\over 2n-1}
$$
So,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k {(-1)^n 2n\over(2n-1)(2n+1) }=
 {1\over 2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \Bigl[{(-1)^{n-1} \over 2n+1}+  {(-1)^{n-1} \over 2n-1}\Bigr]. 
$$
The series is collapsing (the left hand term in one parenthetical expression below cancels with the right hand term in the next parenthetical expression):
$$\eqalign{
 \textstyle{1\over 2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \Bigl[{(-1)^{n-1} \over 2n+1}+  {(-1)^{n-1} \over 2n-1}\Bigr] 
&= \textstyle{1\over 2} \Bigl[ (\color{maroon}{1\over3}+1 ) - (\color{darkgreen}{1\over5}+\color{maroon}{1\over3} )
-({1\over7}+\color{darkgreen}{1\over5})+\cdots +(-1)^{k-1}({1\over 2k+1}+{1\over2k-1} )    \Bigr]\cr
&= \textstyle{1\over 2} \bigl[1   +(-1)^{k-1} {1\over 2k+1}  \bigr].
}
$$